# Monte Carlo Simulation of Irregular Shape

Tags: matlab, math, simulation, montecarlo

need a working example of how to do this, i have a bmp file showing the shape of a lake, the bmp's size is the rectangular area and known. i need to take this picture and estimate the lake size. so far, i have a script that generates a giant matrix of each pixel, telling me whether or not it's in the lake - but this isn't monte carlo! i need to generate random points and compare them against the shape somehow, this is where i'm getting stuck. i don't understand how to compare here, i don't have an equation for the shape or lines, i only have exact point information - either it is or isn't in the lake. so i guess i have the exact area already, but i need to find a way to compare random points against this.

```
function Yes = Point_In_Lake(x,y,image_pixel)

[pHeight,pWidth]=size(image_pixel);
    %pHeight = Height in pixel
    %pWidth = Width in pixel

width = 1000; %width is the actual width of the lake
height = 500; %height is the actual height of the lake

%converting x_value to pixel_value in image_pixel
point_x_pixel = x*pWidth/width;  
xl = floor(point_x_pixel)+1;
xu = min(ceil(point_x_pixel)+1,pWidth);

%converting y_value to pixel_value in image_pixel
point_y_pixel = y*pHeight/height;
yl = floor(point_y_pixel)+1;
yu = min(ceil(point_y_pixel)+1,pHeight);

%Finally, perform the check whether the point is in the lake 
if (image_pixel(yl,xl)~=0)&&(image_pixel(yl,xu)~=0)&&(image_pixel(yu,xl)~=0)&&(image_pixel(yu,xu)~=0)
    Yes=0;
else
    Yes=1;
end
```

Comment: I don't quite get where your problem is. I would assume the whole purpose of the Monte Carlo method is not having to evaluate all pixels but only a randomly choosen part of it. If you are able to check if a specific pixel is inside the lake or not you got everything you need. Just generate some uniformly choosen points, evaluate whether they are in the lake or not and extrapolate from there - or am I missing something?

Comment: The problem lies within what you stated "evaluate whether they are in the lake or not" - this is what i need an example of.

Comment: How do you determine whether a given pixel is in lake or not when you iterate through all the pixels?  That logic would be the same regardless of how you arrived at the pixel.  In Monte Carlo you just generate the pixel locations at random.  Count what proportion of your random pixels are lake pixels, divide by the total number you generated.  That proportion times the image size is an estimate of the size of the lake.

Comment: If your goal is to determine lake size without evaluating too many pixels, monte carlo is probably not a very efficient way. You would for example like to spread out your sampling points instead of selecting them randomly (and thus perhaps sampling many from a small area)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the solution:

```
binaryMap = image_pixel

for i = 1:numel(image_pixel)

 xrand = randperm(size(image_pixel,1),1); 

 yrand = randperm(size(image_pixel,2),1); 

 Yes(i) = Point_In_Lake(xrand,yrand,binaryMap);

end

PercentLake = length(find(Yes==1))/length(Yes);

LakeArea = (PercentLake * 500000)/43560;
```